# Verifying solution of difference equation?

Tags: stochastic-processes, recurrence-relations

I have the following difference equation -

$2h_{x+1} - 5h + 2h_{x-1} = 0$ for $x = 1, 2, ...., 19$

The boundary conditions are $h_0 = 1$ and $h_{20} = 0$

How would I go about verifying that $h_x = At_1^x + Bt_2^x$ for $x = 0, 1, ..., 20$ is a general solution of this equation? And that $t_1$ and $t_2$ are roots of the quadratic equation $2t^2 - 5t + 2 = 0$?

Comment: Is it $2h_{x+1} - 5h_x + 2h_{x-1} = 0$ ? If yes, please edit.

Comment: Yes that's right, fixed it.

Comment: Maybe you can show that $h_x=t_1^x$ solves the difference equation, then that $h_x=t_2^x$ solves it as well, then the full case? What is stopping you?

Comment: Well taking the $h_x = t_1^x$ that gives me $2t_1^{x+1} - 5t_1^x + 2t_1^{x-1} = 0$ which then gives $t_1^{x-1}(2t_1 - 5t_1 + 2) = 0$. Now I have no value for $t_1$ so I can't say it verifies it is a solution of the equation. I run into the same problem again with the second question in that I have no values for $t_1, t_2$ so I can't say they are the roots of the quadratic. That's the issues I'm having?